# Piping in Docker exec command returns an error

Tags: docker, exec

The command I try to execute

```
docker exec apache_mp 'find / -type f -name artisan 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"'
```

returns

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"find / -type f -name artisan 2>&1 |
>   grep -v Permission\": stat find / -type f -name artisan 2>&1 | grep -v
>   Permission: no such file or directory": unknown

Which is weird, as when running the same command from [portainer](https://portainer.io/) it does work. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker assumes that the first argument after the container name should be the binary to be executed. As `'find / -type f -name artisan 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"'` is in brackets, docker thinks that the whole thing is the name of the binary.

You can get it to work by using bash as the binary:

```
docker exec apache_mp /bin/bash -c ' find / -type f -name artisan 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"'
```

Comment: `docker exec -it -u root splunkuniversalforwarder bash -c 'find -iname "*.conf"  | xargs -d'\''\n'\'' grep forward-server'` in my case